# How to Better the Queue?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

I have a question and maybe this for the moderators as well. How does one know that one is doing a good job when doing the Queue about Posts like Edits, and Low-Quality Posts and so on. My thoughts are since I came here to discuss about it. Is there a way we can make a question to be temporarily closed until the OP reviews it, besides doing the close, and reopen procedure. Maybe extend it someone of higher reputation to reopen a temporarily low quality post that has details missing especially if its a first post, and the user added the details it was missing. Maybe this post can be a Sandbox for improving the Queue, and its management, especially for the users interested in the sites workings.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. This IMO is easily abused. Anyways, there are significant changes to the review queue coming down the pipe, I'd recommend reading the full post on meta.

Comment: @DonThousand This is exactly what we need discussion, so are there ways to improve it though like a council of higher more-involved users, and moderators?

Comment: Again, there are serious changes coming down the pipeline. Anyways, we don't have all that much control over review queues, it's more of a meta topic, so please read the post on meta about the changes to them.

Comment: "Is there a way we can make a question to be temporarily closed until the OP reviews it, besides doing the close, and reopen procedure." I do not understand how this differs from the current procedure. We close the question (temporarily). If it gets modified we review if the modifactions are fine and reopene. It's not clear what part of the process could be tossed out. *Maybe* we could reduce the number of votes needed to speed it up. If this is the idea.

Comment: @quid Yes. That is my idea partially like less votes, or trusted users votes, but other ideas can be posted here too as discussion.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include arguments that what @quid reveals as the current procedure, is problematic, as you see it?  Because without such arguments, I'm not convinced that current procedures for closing and reopening need to be changed.  Currently it takes **five users** to even close a question, unless the question is a duplicate, and one of the close-voters has earned a gold badge in a tag used by the asker.  Note that just as a dupe can be closed by one user with a gold badge in the tag, it can also be reopened by one user with a gold badge in the tag.

Comment: @DonThousand:  A link to the Meta Question you have in mind, [Improving the Review Queues - Project overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview) ?

Comment: @hardmath yup, that's the one

Comment: The best way to improve the review queues, and make them more efficient, is for more eligible reviewers commit to doing some reviewing.